# what it means by "populate" in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate

so generally what is "[populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html)"? referring to some action to the database.

I have heard it before but never got it right..

Comment: Please start here - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html. It is a good starting point. You can edit your question to ask a solution for a specific case or point regarding `populate`. Currently it appears to be too broad.

Comment: newbies have limited abilities to go through documents. Looking back, i think the answer i got from below made a lot more sense back then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a document pointing to another document (i.e. contains an ID reference), populate will fetch the referenced document.

For instance, if you have:

```
{
  "__id" : "a",
  "className" : "astroPhysics",
  "teacher" : "b"
}
```

and

```
{
  "__id" : "b",
  "teacherName" : "John Smith"
}
```

getting `a` and populating `teacher` will give the following result:

```
{
  "__id" : "a",
  "className" : "astroPhysics",
  "teacher" : {
      "__id" : "b",
      "teacherName" : "John Smith"
  }
}
```